# Check to see if element of one list exists in another list

Tags: java, excel

I have a list of header values from an excel spreadsheet that is set up to look like a flat table. I also have a list defining the key fields of the table that the excel sheet will be inserted to. I basically want to iterate through the list of header fields, and the header exists in the list of key fields, add it to a map of some sort. What's the best way to check if the values in one list exist in another?

Comment: What does this have to do with Java or math? :-)

Comment: Sorry, the language is java. And Math was an accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe turning your list of keys into a `Set` object will give you the functionality you're looking for.

```
Set<String> keys = new HashSet<String>(listOKeys);

for (String header : listOHeaders) {
    if (keys.contains(header)) {
        // process
    }
}
```

Comment: List has a contains method as well, although using the HashSet will most likely be faster.

Comment: @Andrei:  Yup, O(n) for List vs O(lg n) for HashSet, unless I'm misunderstanding something.  A trivial distinction for small data sets, but defaulting to efficiency is rarely a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
List myList = //...
List another = //...
myList.retainAll(another);
```

Comment: I only need to check if the values exist. If the header is in the list of key fields, then I will proceed to add that header along with it's row value to a Map. If I'm not mistaken, the retainAll will just drop out any values not in the list of keys, giving me a clone of the keys list that I already have